# Get-WMIObject Speed Property Error (PowerShell)

Tags: windows, powershell, ram, get-wmiobject

I have a script that I am working on to pull RAM information.  It currently exports the Max Ram Accepted, Ram Slots, Ram Sticks installed, Total RAM installed, Computer name, and loggedonuser.

I am trying to add the speed property to the out-file but for some reason, this is not exporting.  This is what I have for the command:

```
$Speed = get-WMIobject -class win32_PhysicalMemory | measure-object -property speed -sum
```

and for the `out-file`. I have:

```
"Ram Speed:" -f $($speed.Sum) | Out-File "$ExportPath\$computerName-Memory_Scan.txt
```

When I run the command on the console, it writes to the screen fine but when I try to export to a text file, all I get is "Ram Speed:" and no data.  What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the format item `{0}`:

```
"Ram Speed: {0}" -f $($speed.Sum) | Out-File "$ExportPath\$computerName-Memory_Scan.txt
```

Comment: That was it! Knew it had to be something crazy simple that I was needing.  Thank you sir!